# perl read line by line with global variable

Tags: regex, perl, email

i have a perl script-

```
#!/usr/bin/perl;
my $email = '[a-zA-Z0-9._]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._]+.[a-zA-Z0-9._]{2,4}';
open(FILE,'emails');
while (<FILE>) { 
    my $emails_not_found = 1;
    if ( m/$email/ ) { 
        print($_); 
        my $emails_not_found = 0; 
    } 
    if ( $emails_not_found ) {
        print "no emails\n";
    }
}  
close FILE;
```

the file `emails` is:

```
sdfasd@asd 
asdf
```

so, as you can see, the script will not match regex to any of the lines. however, it outputs this-

```
no emails
no emails
```

i want it to output 'no emails' ONCE if it doesn't match the regex pattern at all. If it only matches the regex pattern just once, it will print that line and output 'no emails' for the other
line :( I just want it to output either JUST the lines with the emails, or output 1 line that says 'no emails'. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you checking for email addresses using a regex that doesn't check for valid email addresses? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, I changed the emails file name in order to test on my machine:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

#output either JUST the lines with emails
# or
#1 line that says 'no emails'
use strict;
use warnings;

my $email = '[a-z0-9\._]+@[a-z0-9\._]+\.[a-z0-9\._]{2,4}';
open(FILE,'./email.txt');
my $emails_not_found = 1;
while (<FILE>) {
    if ( m/$email/i ) {
        print($_);
        $emails_not_found = 0;
    }
}

if ( $emails_not_found == 1) {
    print "no emails\n";
}
close FILE;
```

#### Test file

```
sdfasd@asd
asdf
aaa@aaa.com
AAA@AAA.COM
```

#### Output

```
aaa@aaa.com
AAA@AAA.COM
```

Comment: Thank you very much :) I appreciate the elaboration- it made this much easier to understand. just so you know, you don't need to do $emails_not_found == 1, because if the value is 1 or 0, perl can read it as a boolean, so you can write it as if ( $emails_not_found )

Answer (score 3):

Consider using a module, such as [Regexp::Common::Email::Address](http://search.cpan.org/~cwest/Regexp-Common-Email-Address-1.01/lib/Regexp/Common/Email/Address.pm), "...to match email addresses as defined by RFC 2822":

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Regexp::Common qw/Email::Address/;

my $emailFound = 0;
open my $fh, '<', 'emails' or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    if (/$RE{Email}{Address}/) {
        print;
        $emailFound = 1;
    }
}

close $fh;

print "no emails\n" if !$emailFound;
```

Hope this helps!